# install ubuntu 12.10 issue

Tags: 12.10, grub2

I'm installing Ubuntu 12.10 along side windows 7. I have installed windows then Ubuntu 12.10, each on a different partition. while choosing where to install boot loader I left the default, it was my hard disk name in general not a specific sda or something like that. everything was fine and after rebooting again windows start up logo appeared. I tried to add Ubuntu to Windows boot list using easyBCD and it returned success. Now I can see it windows boot menu but after opting Ubuntu a message and grub > prompt appears. I'm totally confused, help please. thanks and happy new year. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exact same thing happened to me, how I fixed it was I booted into ubuntu live cd and used boot repair (information can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) using recommended repair.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from your install media again. Open the **Disks** program and discover the reference toy your hard disk, probably `/dev/sda`. Then open a terminal and type `sudo grub-install /dev/XXX` where XXX is the drive name.

Reboot to check if the problem is solved or not.